# I want the user be able to search for special food like pizza or burgers in foursquare API from my application

Tags: android, foursquare

I want the user be able to search for special food like pizza or burgers in foursquare API from my application. I can not find a endpoint related to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [venues/explore](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore) endpoint and use 'pizza' or 'burgers' as a `query` parameter.